# Joomla создание блоков

Tags: html, joomla, cms

Начал недавно учить Joomla! 3. Я нашел много информации по поводу как создавать что-либо. Но интересует сама суть однго из "правильных" вариантов создания блока. Я знаю немного Drupal, там все на блоках. Их надо создавать и расширять через модули. В Joomla так же можно делать? Например :
[пример страницы](http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2017/09/29/0014/0699/975547/47/4c3489867b.jpg)

И каждый модуль создавать самому через админ панель? Только какой тип таким модулям задать? Такой подход правильный?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно сделать из блоков(Модули), правильно не правильно это одно, но зато будет работать ,  сам делал пару Одностраничных сайтов на базе модулей, 
в шаблоне есть файл templateDetails.xml прописываете названия модулей примерно как на этой картинке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

дальше в шаблоне  прописываете

```html
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="Названия модуля" />
```

Comment: Благодарю. Мне лендинг надо сделать, вот думал делает так кто-то или нет. Ответ положительный :)